# How to make file upload progress bar in Gravity Forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want users of my site to see the process of uploading a file, because sometimes they send it before it's uploaded completely.
Gravity Forms don't have this option initially.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[File Upload Pro](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-file-upload-pro/) displays a tasty progress bar if you're interested a premium option. I'm not aware of a snippet that does this for Gravity Forms.